# SWIG function not printing output

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm having a prblem in executing a function which I've written in C. I've made and interface file which is given below:

```
%module cnode
%{
#include "cnode.h"
%}
%include "cnode.h"
```

And here is the C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cnode.h"
void kill(void)
{
printf("Method executed\n");
}
```

The header file:

```
void kill(void);
```

When I'm trying to execute it in the python interpreter, I don't get the output. Is there a problem with the declarations or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, kill() is a predefined function so it won't work. Changing name of function works fine.